# unable to view own profile in moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am new in moodle administration! I am using moodlem 3.2. logged in with administrator, if i open my own profile it redirects me to this page:

http://moodle_site.com/ExamOnline/user/profile.php?id=2

And it show this error message:

"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /ExamOnline/user/profile.php on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

same error message shows if i try to uninstall any moodle plugin

Comment: URL NOT WORKING

Comment: this is just the example to understand the directory and the file it is redirecting to! i.e. "user/profile.php" @Hacker

Comment: mode_security might be an issue. its happen for me like this problem after i enabled mode_security.
i turned off mode_security. and all its ok my question, turn off mode_security its good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be 2 possibilities:

- **profile.php** file permission might not be correct or mode_security
  might be an issue.
- The permission might not be enabled like user:editownprofile

Comment: yeah, mod_security was the issue, I have disabled it  from the cpanel  panel and it worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered similar issue in Namecheap hosting.
Tried with this

```html
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

inside .htaccess - but no luck.

Contacted tech support team and they disabled "mod_security" Web Application Firewall of Apache to fix it.